# Listing product titles of products added to cart via shortcode in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to list products that have been added to cart in WooCommerce via shortcode. I have managed to get this far, however it only lists one product with this code. I want to list each product in a different line, preferably with the link back to the product.

Here is my code:

```
// Add Shortcode [bag_products]
function get_cart_products() {
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach( $cart as $cart_item ){
return $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
}
}
add_shortcode( 'bag_products', 'get_cart_products' );
```

Please guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
// Add Shortcode [bag_products]
function get_cart_products() {
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
 $cart_items = "<table><tr>";
 foreach( $cart as $cart_item ){
   $cart_items .= '<td>'.$cart_item['data']->get_title().'</td>';
 }
 $cart_items .= "</tr></table>";
 return $cart_items;
}
add_shortcode( 'bag_products', 'get_cart_products' );
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil Dora, the products are listed but are listed in the same line. Can you please help me in listing them in separate lines? Thanks.

Comment: now check this answer, I updated it. You use HTML for formatting your content like this.

Comment: it is now not returning anything. The field is blank. I appreciate your time and your help.

Comment: sorry, that was a silly mistake now you can copy and check this answer.

Comment: Thank you @Sunil Dora. This one works. I edited your code a little bit to put them in different lines.